# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0') aws lambda to drop spam emails in Workmail

Tags: javascript, aws-lambda

I have created a lambda function using the example provided by AWS to drop spam emails that meet the IF condition.

I have also added permissions to allow this lambda to use my workmail organization as shown here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/workmail/latest/adminguide/lambda.html

I'm checking the Cloudwatch logs and it keeps giving an error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0') at line 4.

Here's the code in index.js

```
exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
console.log('Spam filter');

var sesNotification = event.Records[0].ses;
console.log("SES Notification:\n", JSON.stringify(sesNotification, null, 2));

// Check if any spam check failed
if (sesNotification.receipt.spfVerdict.status === 'FAIL'
        || sesNotification.receipt.dkimVerdict.status === 'FAIL'
        || sesNotification.receipt.spamVerdict.status === 'FAIL'
        || sesNotification.receipt.virusVerdict.status === 'FAIL') {
    console.log('Dropping spam');
    // Stop processing rule set, dropping message
    callback(null, {'disposition':'STOP_RULE_SET'});
} else {
    callback(null, null);   
}
```

};

Comment: To add: I have also added a flow rule which runs the above lambda function in my workmail organization and that's where I'm getting the error.

Comment: The first thing to do is to log the value of `event`. Evidently it doesn't have a `Records` property, so `event.Records` will be undefined and hence you will get the error in your title.